# Heroku- How can I update an existing Heroku app?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a project on Heroku and I do some changes about the project and when I write to "git push heroku master" I get an error.

```
To https://git.heroku.com/webookapp.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/webookapp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I ran the following commands in order.

```
heroku git:remote -a webookapp
git add .
git commit -m "update"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git is telling you that the *remote reference* you are pushing to has changed and that you should update it first - Someone pushed their work before you and git needs you to retrieve that work to evaluate whether or not your work can be applied cleanly on top. The *hint* is in the hint:

> This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes(e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Try `git pull` (you may need to resolve conflicts) and then `git push` again.